# Compare array elements

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

Is there a more elegant way in CoffeeScript to compare elements within arrays?

For "is any of these elements in the array" I do:

`if "b0" in myArr or "b1" in myArr or "b1" in myArr`

And for "are all of these elements in the array" I do:

`if "b0" in myArr and "b1" in myArr and "b1" in myArr`

Thank you very much for your help on this beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

> For "is any of these elements in the array" I do:
>       if "b0" in myArr or "b1" in myArr or "b1" in myArr

It is convenient to use Array methods for this. [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is useful:

```
['b0', 'b1', 'b2'].some(function(el) {
    return myArr.indexOf(el) > -1;
});
```

> And for "are all of these elements in the array" I do:
>   if "b0" in myArr and "b1" in myArr and "b1" in myArr

And here you can use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
['b0', 'b1', 'b2'].every(function(el) {
    return myArr.indexOf(el) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you dfsq for that little trick. I was sure CoffeeScript had something convenient "build in", but couldn't find proper examples anymore.

Comment: I'm not coffescript guy, but I don't think it has something that specific. After all, it's just normal JS. You just need to translate it to CS syntax.